# IIS, Under Application Pool Identity HttpWebRequest class does not works

Tags: iis, httpwebrequest, application-pool, applicationpoolidentity

IIS, Under Application Pool Identity HttpWebRequest class does not works. I use DOMAIN NETWORK and PROXY, but when I use Custom Account (with domain\someuser) it is works, Please help someone, how can it works with ApplicationPoolIdentity?